# Qt: transparent QRubberBand?

Tags: user-interface, qt, opengl, rubber-band

I'm trying to draw a QRubberBand on a QGLWidget. For some reason the area of the rubber band is drawn as opaque and I don't see what's behind it. This kinda beats the purpose of the rubber band as a way to select stuff inside it.
I've seen in docs for QStyleOptionRubberBand that there's an 'opaque' member but I have no idea how to access this in the default style or how to change it.

Anybody ever done this?

Comment: Please add the source code where you are dealing with the QRubberBand. It's difficult to figure out whether it's a bug on your end, Qt's end, or a feature of Qt.

Comment: The code isn't really something special to look at. its basically the same code as the QRubberBand docs: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qrubberband.html

Answer (score 0):

It would be great having any source code ?
But here are how I would attempt to fix the problem :

1. Subclass QRubberBand
2. Redefine PaintEvent method
3. call iniStyleOption to activate style options of your choice

Hope it helps !